# "Error creating container 'system32-rails-app-1': Access denied for 'c:\windows\system32\files' folder"

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose, deployment

> I am encountering an issue while trying to create a container named system32-rails-app-1 in Docker on a Windows machine. The error message I receive is:

> Error response from daemon: mkdir c:\windows\system32\files: access is denied.

> I believe this error is related to folder permissions, as it is trying to create the folder c:\windows\system32\files and being denied access. I am running Docker with administrator privileges, but the problem persists.

Here's some additional context:

- Docker version: [4.22.0]
- Windows version: [22H2]
- Docker command used: [docker-compose up]

Comment: Looks like your dockerfile is using `C:\Windows\System32` as its working directory. Maybe fix that first